# How to make and handle Ajax calls using backbone.js

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am new to the backbone. I tried to do ajax call in the below manner. And I am not sure how to handle the data from my get request?
Here is the code:

//Interacting with the server

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url:'http://api.geonames.org/astergdemJSON?formatted=true&lat=50.01&lng=10.2&username=demo&style=full'
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new UserModel();
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        alert('do awesome stuff here');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you make `fetch()`, Backbone will send an GET ajax request to the endpoint you specifiend on `url`.

When you call `.fetch`, the model will trigger a `request` event, and when you receive it, parse it and set it to the model, the model will trigger a `sync` event.

If you want to change any data before setting it to the model, override the method `parse` on you model. It receives the raw data from the GET request and must return what is going to be set to your model.

If you want extra success and error callbacks, pass them in you your `fecth({ success: ..., error: ... })`. Success callback is triggered after setting and parsing the values to the model and before sync event. Error callback is triggered before error event. Look the documentation for more details. It is not necessary to pass any of those callbacks.

So, it would be something like:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model = new UserModel();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
        this.model.fetch();
    },
    render: function() {
        alert('My model loaded: ' + this.model.toJSON());
    }
});
```

And, that's it. Backbone makes almost everything for you.

Hope I've helped.

Comment: Thanks Walter. I,s working fine. And I tried adding success/error call backs. When I run it, callbacks are getting triggered before render.

Comment: Success callback is triggered after setting and parsing the values to the model and before `sync` event. Error callback is triggered before `error` event. That's why, in this example, they are being executed before `render`, since `render` is executed when you receive the `sync`.